# Atribuir o retorno de um método à uma variável apenas se esse não for nil

Tags: ruby

gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais ruby-like de atribuir o retorno de um método à uma variável apenas se esse não for nil.

Um código de exemplo de como funcionaria de uma  forma, digamos, feia.

```
def meu_metodo(valor)
  valor if valor.even?
end

variavel = nil

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6].each do |valor|
  tmp = meu_metodo(valor)
  variavel = tmp unless tmp.nil?
  puts variavel
end
```

Coloria em uma variável temporária para depois realizar o teste, existe alguma forma de realizar esse teste já na atribuição?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais sucinta de escrever um tipo de verificação de não nulidade de um objeto é usando `variavel ||= objetivo`, que é uma contração da expressão `variavel = variavel || objetivo`. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
def meu_metodo(valor)
  valor if valor.even?
end

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6].each do |valor|
  tmp ||= meu_metodo(valor)
  puts(tmp) if tmp
end
```

É importante notar que isso só é possível porque tmp volta a ser nil no início de cada ciclo desse each. Caso seja necessário usar uma variável externa ao bloco, por qualquer motivo que seja, em algum momento ela terá de ser redefinida como nil, pois caso não seja feito, apenas funcionará para a primeira vez em que o resultado não for nulo ou falso.